# LaTeX CV Deedy-resume: how to remove line after the name?

Tags: xetex, cv, deedy-resume

Good evening everyone,

I searched everywhere how to remove the line after my name and adress in LaTeX deedy resume, but I didn't find it. Could you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a minimal working example so that we can modify it to answer your question.

Comment: Please consider to accept my answer if it was most helpful for you. That is the way here to say "Thank you for the help" ...

Answer (score 2):

You can patch the used class with the following lines in your preamble of your cv:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\namesection}{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}{\rule{\paperwidth}{0pt}}{}{}
```

Based on the templates example cv you have then the complete code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Deedy - One Page Two Column Resume
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.2 (16/9/2014)
%
% Original author:
% Debarghya Das (http://debarghyadas.com)
%
% Original repository:
% https://github.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume
%
% IMPORTANT: THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX
%
% This template uses several fonts not included with Windows/Linux by
% default. If you get compilation errors saying a font is missing, find the line
% on which the font is used and either change it to a font included with your
% operating system or comment the line out to use the default font.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
% TODO:
% 1. Integrate biber/bibtex for article citation under publications.
% 2. Figure out a smoother way for the document to flow onto the next page.
% 3. Add styling information for a "Projects/Hacks" section.
% 4. Add location/address information
% 5. Merge OpenFont and MacFonts as a single sty with options.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% CHANGELOG:
% v1.1:
% 1. Fixed several compilation bugs with \renewcommand
% 2. Got Open-source fonts (Windows/Linux support)
% 3. Added Last Updated
% 4. Move Title styling into .sty
% 5. Commented .sty file.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Known Issues:
% 1. Overflows onto second page if any column's contents are more than the
% vertical limit
% 2. Hacky space on the first bullet point on the second column.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}


\usepackage{etoolbox} % <===============================================
\patchcmd{\namesection}{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}{\rule{\paperwidth}{0pt}}{}{}


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     LAST UPDATED DATE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lastupdated

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     TITLE NAME
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\namesection{Debarghya}{Das}{ \urlstyle{same}\href{http://debarghyadas.com}{debarghyadas.com}| \href{http://fb.co/dd}{fb.co/dd}\\
\href{mailto:deedy@fb.com}{deedy@fb.com} | 607.379.5733 | \href{mailto:dd367@cornell.edu}{dd367@cornell.edu}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN ONE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EDUCATION
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Education} 

\subsection{Cornell University}
\descript{MEng in Computer Science}
\location{Dec 2014 | Ithaca, NY}
\sectionsep

\subsection{Cornell University}
\descript{BS in Computer Science}
\location{May 2014 | Ithaca, NY}
College of Engineering \\
Magna Cum Laude\\
\location{ Cum. GPA: 3.83 / 4.0 \\
Major GPA: 3.9 / 4.0}
\sectionsep

\subsection{La Martiniere for Boys}
\location{Grad. May 2011|  Kolkata, India}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     LINKS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Links} 
Facebook:// \href{https://facebook/dd}{\bf dd} \\
Github:// \href{https://github.com/deedydas}{\bf deedydas} \\
LinkedIn://  \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/debarghyadas}{\bf debarghyadas} \\
YouTube://  \href{https://www.youtube.com/user/DeedyDash007}{\bf DeedyDash007} \\
Twitter://  \href{https://twitter.com/debarghya_das}{\bf @debarghya\_das} \\
Quora://  \href{https://www.quora.com/Debarghya-Das}{\bf Debarghya-Das}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     COURSEWORK
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Coursework}
\subsection{Graduate}
Advanced Machine Learning \\
Open Source Software Engineering \\
Advanced Interactive Graphics \\
Compilers + Practicum \\
Cloud Computing \\
Evolutionary Computation \\
Defending Computer Networks \\
Machine Learning \\
\sectionsep

\subsection{Undergraduate}
Information Retrieval \\
Operating Systems \\
Artificial Intelligence + Practicum \\
Functional Programming \\
Computer Graphics + Practicum \\
{\footnotesize \textit{\textbf{(Research Asst. \& Teaching Asst 2x) }}} \\
Unix Tools and Scripting \\

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     SKILLS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\section{Skills}
%\subsection{Programming}
%\location{Over 5000 lines:}
%Java \textbullet{}   Shell \textbullet{} Python \textbullet{} Javascript \\
%OCaml \textbullet{} Matlab \textbullet{} Rails \textbullet{} \LaTeX\ \\ 
%\location{Over 1000 lines:}
%C \textbullet{} C++ \textbullet{} CSS \textbullet{} PHP \textbullet{} Assembly \\
%\location{Familiar:}
%AS3 \textbullet{} iOS \textbullet{} Android \textbullet{} MySQL
%\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN TWO
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EXPERIENCE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Experience}
\runsubsection{Facebook}
\descript{| Software Engineer }
\location{Jan 2015 - Present | New York, NY}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Coursera}
\descript{| KPCB Fellow + Software Engineering Intern }
\location{June 2014 – Sep 2014 | Mountain View, CA}
\vspace{\topsep} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space
\begin{tightemize}
\item 52 out of 2500 applicants chosen to be a KPCB Fellow 2014.
\item Led and shipped Yoda - the admin interface for the new Phoenix platform. 
\item Full-stack developer - Wrote and reviewed code for JS using Backbone, Jade, Stylus and Require and Scala using Play
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Google}
\descript{| Software Engineering Intern }
\location{May 2013 – Aug 2013 | Mountain View, CA}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Worked on the YouTube Captions team, in Javascript and Python to plan, to design and develop the full stack to add and edit Automatic Speech Recognition captions. In production.
\item Created a backbone.js-like framework for the Captions editor.
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Phabricator}
\descript{| Open Source Contributor \& Team Leader}
\location{Jan 2013 – May 2013 | Palo Alto, CA \& Ithaca, NY}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Phabricator is used daily by Facebook, Dropbox, Quora, Asana and more.
\item I created the Meme generator and more in PHP and Shell.
\item Led a team from MIT, Cornell, IC London and UHelsinki for the project.
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     RESEARCH
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Research}
\runsubsection{Cornell Robot Learning Lab}
\descript{| Researcher}
\location{Jan 2014 – Jan 2015 | Ithaca, NY}
Worked with \textbf{\href{http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ashesh/}{Ashesh Jain}} and \textbf{\href{http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asaxena/}{Prof Ashutosh Saxena}} to create \textbf{PlanIt}, a tool which  learns from large scale user preference feedback to plan robot trajectories in human environments.  
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Cornell Phonetics Lab}
\descript{| Head Undergraduate Researcher}
\location{Mar 2012 – May 2013 | Ithaca, NY}
Led the development of \textbf{QuickTongue}, the first ever breakthrough tongue-controlled game with \textbf{\href{http://conf.ling.cornell.edu/~tilsen/}{Prof Sam Tilsen}} to aid in Linguistics research. 
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     AWARDS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Awards} 
\begin{tabular}{rll}
2014         & top 52/2500  & KPCB Engineering Fellow\\
2014         & 1\textsuperscript{st}/50  & Microsoft Coding Competition, Cornell\\
2013         & National  & Jump Trading Challenge Finalist\\
2013     & 7\textsuperscript{th}/120 & CS 3410 Cache Race Bot Tournament  \\
2012     & 2\textsuperscript{nd}/150 & CS 3110 Biannual Intra-Class Bot Tournament \\
2011     & National & Indian National Mathematics Olympiad (INMO) Finalist \\
\end{tabular}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     PUBLICATIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\section{Publications} 
%\renewcommand\refname{\vskip -1.5cm} % Couldn't get this working from the .cls file
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
%\bibliography{publications}
%\nocite{*}

\end{minipage} 
\end{document}
```

and the result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The line present below the name and address is a part of the basic structure of the program and thus you need to refer to the `Commands.cls` file. You may note that there are 2 files: `Commands.cls` & `Main.tex` and a folder: `fonts` present by default.

In the `Commands.cls` file, find the block of code that begins with a comment `Name Command`.

You need to make an edit to the line: `\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}`

Make the width of the line to `0 pt` from the default `0.4 pt` or leave the braces blank `{}`.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your answer is a bit specific for a particular editor (you talk about _the left pane_ and to _scroll down_ etc. The poster of the question might not have the same editor as you, and many other people that look at this question later will also have a different editor. Therefore, your answer would improve if you remove any reference to the editor and just say 'modify this line in `Commands.cls`'. It is also better not to reference the specific line number because this may change in a future version of Deedy Resume, or mention it but specify which version of the file you have.

Comment: @Marijn, thank you for your suggestions. I have made the suggested edits.

Answer (score 0):

In `deedy-resume-openfont.sty` the macro dealing with the title and heading is as follows

```
% Name command
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
    \centering{
        \sffamily
        \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\fontsize{40pt}{10cm}\selectfont #1 
        \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2
    } \\
    \vspace{5pt}
    \centering{ \color{headings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #3}
    \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
    \vspace{-15pt}
}
```

Just replace the line

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
```

with

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule[\baselineskip]{\paperwidth}{0pt}}
```

Comment: The solution given by @Mensch is much better than this as it doesn't mess with the style files manually.